# Java SWT menubar item stuck "on" after subshell created

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

This is undoubtedly a trivial problem, but I just cannot seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  The situation is very simple: I have an application that creates an additional dialog window to show something to the user.  The main application has a menubar with menu items that have keyboard shortcuts.  When I invoke a menu item using the keyboard shortcut, and the main program creates the new window, then when the user *closes* the new window and is shown the main application again, the menubar item stays stuck with a highlighted/"turned on" look.  The code to replicate what I'm seeing on Mac OS with SWT 4.2 is this:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class tester
{
    public static void createShell(Shell parent) {
        final Shell newShell = new Shell(parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.RESIZE);
        newShell.setSize(100,100);
        newShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        Button closeButton = new Button(newShell, SWT.NONE);
        closeButton.setText("Close");
        closeButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                newShell.close();
            }
        });

        newShell.open();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.setSize(200, 100);

        Menu menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
        shell.setMenuBar(menuBar);

        MenuItem item = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
        item.setText("Foo");

        Menu fooMenu = new Menu(item);
        item.setMenu(fooMenu);

        MenuItem barMenu = new MenuItem(fooMenu, SWT.NONE);
        barMenu.setText("Menu item");
        barMenu.setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 + 'F');
        barMenu.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
                createShell(shell);
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

To replicate the problem, run the program above, invoke Command-F from the keyboard, then click on the "Close" button in the window that is created.  It will close the 2nd window and just go back to the original window.  Here's an example of what it looks like after I do that:

[image: screenshot]

The problem is how the "Foo" stays highlighted.  I expect it not to stay highlighted.  And in fact, it does *not* stay highlighted if I pull down the menu and select the menu item, so there is something specific about using the keyboard shortcut that causes this, but I'm at my wits' end trying to figure out what that could be.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything being wrong in that code. So what is left is to work around the issue. While that indicates a hack, it does work. The idea would be to defer execution to a later time, not too much later, but after sufficient time, for the event to complete and the item being deactivated. A first test of using `Display.getDefault().asyncExec()` did not work as expected, so instead I've tried a combination of `invokeLater` with `asyncExec` but that would not so anything. At that point I choose a hammer and called `Thread.currentThread().sleep()` in combination of the above, and that seems to work just fine.

All that would need to change is the `SelectionAdapter` of the barMenu like so:

```
    barMenu.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            // invoke later to give event time to finish, and have
            // the menu item deselected
            javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
              // wait
              try { Thread.currentThread().sleep(100);} catch(Exception ex){}
              // jump back to the SWT thread and do the actual work
              Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
               createShell(shell);
              }});
            }});
        }
    });
```